# Dynamically allocating an array of structs

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, struct

I'm trying to create an array of structs, of which the array size is defined by the user in the program. eg. p[0], p[1], p[2].....

```
typedef struct
{
int score;
}player;

void main()
{
    int numPlayers;

    printf ("\nEnter number of players (1 - 4)\n");
    scanf ("%d", &numPlayers);

}
```

I've tried doing it with both

```
player p[numPlayers];
```

and

```
player *p=malloc(numPlayers*sizeof(player));
```

but both won't compile.
Can anyone see what's going wrong here?

Edit: I'm using VS2010.
I'm getting "expression must have a constant value" for the first one, and "a value of type "void*" cannot be used to initialise an entity of type "player*" for the second one.

Comment: what compile errors are you getting?

Comment: what compiler and what is the compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `player p[numPlayers];` approach calls for a "variable length array". This is a feature which appeared in the GNU C dialect many years ago, and was adopted into the C language in 1999. To get that to compile you need a compiler which recognizes this as an extension, or a C99 compiler.  Variable Length Arrays have a downside: they are usually implemented by allocating the memory on the stack. There is no way to detect whether or not there is enough memory.

The malloc calling syntax you have is fine:

```
player *p=malloc(numPlayers*sizeof(player));
```

However, if you want to write this anywhere in your function, you need to be using a C99 compiler, or a compiler that accepts inter-mingled statements and declarations (like GNU C which has had that as an extension for years before C99 and accepts it by default. In C90, you have to declare the pointer in the block of declarations at the top of the function (or braced statement):  `player *p = NULL;`.  Then later, after the number of players is known, assign to it `p = malloc ...`.

You should post the actual program that doesn't compile. Without that we are only guessing!

Moreover, you have some problems.

Firstly, if you want to call `malloc`, you should include the header `<stdlib.h>` where malloc is declared.

Secondly, `main` should return type `int` not `void`.

Also, check the return value of `scanf`.  The `scanf` function is bad for interactive input. For instance if the user hits Enter, `scanf` keeps waiting for input, looking for those numeric characters, which is unfriendly.  `scanf` also has no error checking in `%d`. If you enter a number that doesn't fit into the type `int` the behavior is simply undefined. This type of input handling is only suitable for quick-and-dirty "throwaway" programs written for the author's own use.

Comment: "...in 1991"? Really? "1999" maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I was indeed calling malloc after scanf. Even changing things around though it's still not working. I used hmjd's code down below into a blank project and I'm still getting the second error I mentioned.

Comment: This is probably because you are actually writing in C++. In C++, you cannot assign a pointer of type `void *` to `player *`. This is not a type safe conversion. The rules are relaxed in C (even though the `void` type came from C++ originally!).  In C++ you need the cast like `player *p = (player *) malloc(...)`.  Did you save your file with a `.cpp` suffix? Anyway, if you're workig in C++, tag your question C++.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be that you've forgotten to `#include <stdlib.h>`. Without a prototype for it, the compiler will assume that `malloc` returns an `int`, which won't convert to a pointer without a cast (but don't use a cast -- include the proper header so the compiler knows the return type instead).

Edit: It's unrelated, but FWIW, `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: And if it happens to be a C++ compiler, it will reject the program because the function is undeclared.

Comment: `main` is totally related because compilers can reject `void main`. You never know; the newbie could have been told by the teacher to use gcc with `-Werror`. :)

Comment: @Kaz: Theoretically, yes. Based on his comments, no.

Comment: stdlib.h is certainly included, but it's still not working. As for the main thing, I just recently found out about that so I'm still trying to remember to change it. Thanks.